# "I might seem strong, but in actuality I am anything but." -- Complete or incomplete?

Tags: sentence-structure, clauses

Is the sentence complete or should it be completed, for example, as follows;

> I might seem strong, but in actuality I am anything but ***strong***.

If the original is complete, please provide any reference that I can confirm from.

P.S. The added ***strong*** seems redundant though, I could use ***that*** instead. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I might seem strong, but in actuality I am anything but.

There is nothing ungrammatical about this version of the sentence that appears in the title of your question. So long as you keep *anything but*, you certainly don't need to repeat *strong*.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anything%20but):

> **anything but** idiom
>   : not at all
>   // He looked *anything but* happy.
>   // Though he said he was happy, he looked *anything but*.
>   // This problem is *anything but* new.

Note the second example sentence that ends with *anything but*. It can do so because the object has already been given in the first part of the sentence.

---

Yet while there is no reason to change the sentence in the title of your question, you might consider rephrasing it slightly if you want to avoid the repetition of *but*:

> I might seem strong, when in actuality I am anything but.
>   Although I might seem strong, in actuality I am anything but.

You can also reorder things a bit if you don't want to *end* the sentence in that way:

> In actuality, I am anything but as strong as I seem.